# Orchard custom module not saving all items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, module, orchardcms

Building my first module in Orchard, and everything but the save (on some fields) is working.  I get no errors on save, the fields just show their default value with no values being inserted/updated in the database table.

I built the module with only one property at first, and then added more to the recordpart once I confirmed things updated from the admin.  Now the new fields show up in the editor, but only the original property (SoldOut) is saving on update or create.  I saw another post that recommended deleting the mappings.bin file, but that didn't change anything.  Thanks for any help!

Here's the main classes:

```
public class ConferencePartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual bool OnlyShowTeaser { get; set; }
    public virtual int TheYear { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime EarlyReg { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RegularReg { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime LateReg { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime ConfirmDate { get; set; }

    public virtual bool SoldOut { get; set; }
    public virtual bool ConferenceSpace { get; set; }

    public virtual int EarlyBirdException { get; set; }

    public virtual string NextConf { get; set; }
}

public class ConferencePart : ContentPart<ConferencePartRecord>
{
    public bool OnlyShowTeaser
    {
        get { return Record.OnlyShowTeaser; }
        set { Record.OnlyShowTeaser = value; }

    }

    public int TheYear
    {
        get { return Record.TheYear; }
        set { Record.TheYear = value; }
    }

    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return Record.StartDate; }
        set { Record.StartDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get { return Record.EndDate; }
        set { Record.EndDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime EarlyReg
    {
        get { return Record.EarlyReg; }
        set { Record.EarlyReg = value; }
    }

    public DateTime RegularReg
    {
        get { return Record.RegularReg; }
        set { Record.RegularReg = value; }
    }

    public DateTime LateReg
    {
        get { return Record.LateReg; }
        set { Record.LateReg = value; }
    }

    public DateTime ConfirmDate
    {
        get { return Record.ConfirmDate; }
        set { Record.ConfirmDate = value; }
    }

    public bool ConferenceSpace
    {
        get { return Record.ConferenceSpace; }
        set { Record.ConferenceSpace = value; }
    }


    public int EarlyBirdException
    {
        get { return Record.EarlyBirdException; }
        set { Record.EarlyBirdException = value; }
    }

    public String NextConf
    {
        get { return Record.NextConf; }
        set { Record.NextConf = value; }
    }

    public bool SoldOut
    {
        get { return Record.SoldOut; }
        set { Record.SoldOut = value; }
    }

}
```

Here is my driver class:

```
public class ConferenceDriver : ContentPartDriver<AeriesConference.Models.ConferencePart>
{
    protected override DriverResult Display(ConferencePart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Conference", () => shapeHelper.Parts_Conference(SoldOut: part.SoldOut));
    }

    //GET
    protected override DriverResult Editor(ConferencePart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Conference_Edit",
            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                TemplateName: "Parts/Conference",
                Model: part,
                Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    //POST
    protected override DriverResult Editor(ConferencePart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

... the migrations.cs class (so you can see my updates - which are all reflected in the DB)

```
    public int Create() {
        // Creating table ConferenceRecord
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column("SoldOut", DbType.Boolean)
        );



        return 1;
    }

    public int UpdateFrom1()
    {

        // Create (or alter) a part called "ConferencePart" and configure it to be "attachable".
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("ConferencePart", part => part
            .Attachable());

        return 2;
    }

    public int UpdateFrom2()
    {
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("OnlyShowTeaser", DbType.Boolean));
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("TheYear", DbType.Int16));
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("StartDate", DbType.DateTime));
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("EndDate", DbType.DateTime));
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("EarlyReg", DbType.DateTime));
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("RegularReg", DbType.DateTime));
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("LateReg", DbType.DateTime));
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("ConfirmDate", DbType.DateTime));
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("ConferenceSpace", DbType.Boolean));
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("EarlyBirdException", DbType.Int16));
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ConferencePartRecord", table => table.AddColumn("NextConf", DbType.String));

        return 3;
    }

}
```

and, finally, my handler class:

```
public class ConferencePartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public ConferencePartHandler(IRepository<ConferencePartRecord> repository)
    {
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I found the issue 5 minutes after posting the question. I had missed one of the datetime fields in the cshtml file for the editor, and when it was saving to the database it was dying on the update since the date column won't take a null.